# Correct format for Objectquery

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq-to-objects

Hi I have a wpf c# with EF project. I am trying to query the ticket entity (which is a mysql view) to get a return for a datagrid.

I can get the query for the staff_id to work from a combo control on the ui.  However when I add the date from the date pickers. It all goes wrong. Can anyone help with my syntax please.

Also I am to do this in LINQ but am really struggling

Here is the function sorry for the lack of formating and I do not know the method to do a code block

```
private void GetTicketsEntered_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   DateTime From = dpTktFrom.SelectedDate ??DateTime.Now;
   string query = "it.staff_id ==" + staff_idComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()
      + "  && it.TicketDate >=DATEIME '" + From.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")+ "'"
      + "'  && it.TicketDate <=DATETIME '" + dpTktTo.SelectedDate.ToString() +"'";

    MessageBox.Show(query);
    // ost_staffViewSource.Source = [generic data source]
    Helpdesk_Tickets.ostEntitiesv2 ostEntitiesv2 = new Helpdesk_Tickets.ostEntitiesv2();

    // Load data into enteredtickets. You can modify this code as needed.
    System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource enteredticketsViewSource = 
      ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("enteredticketsViewSource")));

    System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Helpdesk_Tickets.enteredticket> enteredticketsQuery = 
      this.GetenteredticketsQuery(ostEntitiesv2).Where(query).OrderBy("it.TicketDate desc");

     enteredticketsViewSource.Source = 
       enteredticketsQuery.Execute(System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.AppendOnly);
}
```

Returns this error

> "The query syntax is not valid. Near term ''2016-03-05 12:00:00''  && it.TicketDate <=DATETIME '', line 8, column 98."

This also when I do this it returns the same error

```
string query = "it.staff_id ==" + staff_idComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()

            + "  && it.TicketDate >=DATEIME '2016-03-04 00:00:00'";
```

Any pointers please

Ps I will edit this when I get back to my pc aplogises

Comment: Am I missing what you're using? As far I can see, the table's column in the DB isn't of type *DataTime*. Also, I'm not sure why you're not using the syntax *context.Tickets.Where(...)*. And I'm not certain why those calls to the DB are done rom the view and not in the view model that the controls bind to.

Comment: Hi the field TicketDate is type  DateTime in db. The syntax is auto generated and I modified it. Any better ways welcome ☺

Comment: `DATEIME` looks like a typo.

Comment: Omg how stupid of me 

Comment: So was that the problem?

Comment: When I get home I will check...but ain't going to help